# after changing ubuntu user account and root password all files disappeared and cant run any software

Tags: files, password, root

i did write in terminal:

```
sudo su
```

then changer the root password:

```
passwd
```

and then exit to the user:

```
exit
```

and then changed the user password:

```
sudo passwd username
```

after changing ubuntu user account and root password and reboot all files disappeared and cant run any software, and after opening the terminal the user name and machine name is not colored like before.

[the terminal user name and machine name not colored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FREtU.jpg)

Comment: Your question lacks details. Ubuntu systems usually don't have a root password, so you cannot log in directly as root but use `sudo` to run commands that need root privileges. Please [edit] your question and describe in detail what exactly you did and how you try to access files or software and what happens. What exactly is different from before? How were user name and machine name colored before? BTW: "Terminal" *is* software, so you *can* run some software.

Comment: Please answer all questions or requests for clarification. You still did not explain how exactly you observed that "all files disappeared" or that you "can't run any software". The `passwd` command does not delete any files or remove software. You might have made a mistake in the shell running as root after `sudo su`.

Comment: The only circumstance I can think of which might make files *seem* to have disappeared is if your home directory was encrypted, and requires the old password to unwrap the encryption passphrase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found this file in home directory: README.txt

```
THIS DIRECTORY HAS BEEN UNMOUNTED TO PROTECT YOUR DATA.

From the graphical desktop, click on:
 "Access Your Private Data"

or

From the command line, run:
 ecryptfs-mount-private
```

then i did run `ecryptfs-mount-private`

after that i did add the old password and did work all my files restored.

Comment: You never, ever mentioned in your question that encryption was a factor in your problem. In future, please don't leave out vital details like that when asking questions.

Comment: i did'n mention the encryption because its the answer!, read the question and the answer again, i did change the password, and then i found that linux did encrypt my home directory, how would i know that after i change my password that linux will encrypt my fules?